# Facebook blue background at the top on Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

What could I use to recreate the blue header background on the facebook login page in JFrame?

[image]

It's a school project and our professor asked to make the fb homepage using javax.swing.*; and awt. Here's what mine looks like so far.

[image]

Comment: You can use a button similar to the Create an account and make it unclickable

Comment: I tried that already and it covers out the other jlabels and jtxtfields.

Comment: You could try overriding the `JPanel`'s `paintComponent()` method and use a `GradientPaint` there.

Comment: Swing paints components based on the order of the component. So, if `container` is your `Container` object then do `container.add(blueHeaderButton)` first then do the `container.add(facebookLogoLabel)` and so on..

Comment: *"It's a school project and our professor asked to make the fb homepage using javax.swing and awt"* This professor is incompetent and should be sacked. There is no course in either programming ***or*** design, in which it would actually make sense to set that as an exercise for students.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I believe its an exercise to for us to practice the usage of swing and awt packages. And I'm in college taking up bachelor of science in Information technology, and this is pretty much basic java am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JLabel.
you can add image on JLabel and add Background color

JLabel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
JLabel.setOpaque(true);

add the label first to jframe and add textfield after,
JFrame.add(JLabel); 
JFrame.add(JTextField);

so that the textfield is on the top of jlabel

Comment: Close, but it still covers up the other things even with setOpaque(true). Is there someway I could implement the header within the Jframebackground? like making it have two background colors?

Comment: @Alpha if you add the Jlabel on your Jframe first after the Textfield. the label will be under the textfield. in my example, it will possibly works

Comment: I added the Jlabel for the header after all the affected objects, it works now thanks!